# In case task fails, how to terminate rest of the execution?

Tags: error-handling, ansible

I am running a complex playbook using `shell` in one of my Ansible playbook task. And I am running an upgrade for s/w using `command` module in one of my Ansible playbook tasks.

How do I terminate execution of rest of the playbook in case output of this command includes `failed`?

Currently its silently failing and rest of the playbook executing without alerting any failure.

Below is a part of main playbook which has multiple other tasks:

```yaml
- hosts: abc
  tasks:
    - name: Upgrade S/W 
      include_role:
        name: sw.upgrade
      register: upgrade_result
      tags:
      - upgrade

    - debug:
        msg: "{{upgrade_result}}"
```

and below is task from role:

```yaml
- name: Execute upgrade
  command: "running some upgrade command here"
  async: 7200
  poll: 10
  register: sw_upgrade_hosts
```

I am new to Ansible and tried `failed_when` option but that doesn't give expected result.

Comment: did you try failed_when: upgrade_result.rc != 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using following logic :

For `shell` invoking in Ansible use bash script and can write all shell cmds there.

Next step is to invoke this bash script in ansible ..

```yaml
- name: example of many failed
  ansible.builtin.shell: "./xyz.sh"
  register: ret
  failed_when: >
    ("Error string") or
    (ret.stderr != '') or
    (ret.rc == 10)
```

Something like this could be of help here!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding

> *How do I terminate execution of rest of the playbook in case output of this command includes `failed`?*

you would need to [Define failure](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#defining-failure) with `failed_when`, or could [assert that given expressions are true](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assert_module.html) or [`end_play`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/meta_module.html).